# User deleting another user on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase to develop an Android app. I use Firebase Auth and Firebase Database and I have a user hierarchy where a user can register new users.

To add the new user I was able to do without problems in that I create the new user and do re-authentication of the user who added it. But, I need to make it possible for the user to delete other users who have registered.

In the documentation it says that it is necessary to re-authenticate the user so that he can delete the account. I would like to know if anyone has any tips on how to safely do this?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Client-side deletion of a user other than yourself should be an anomaly. To properly create an administrative function to delete users, use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll take a look at this. :D

Answer (score 1):

As of now we can delete the own account(current loggedin account), but we cannot delete other account

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're looking at only let's users delete their own accounts. Please refer to the following
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users